# How does Python.NET execute .NET code in Python? How does it collect garbage?

Tags: c#, python, .net, garbage-collection, python.net

How does **[Python.NET](http://pythonnet.github.io/)** execute .NET code in Python in same process? 
How does garbage collection work in Python.NET?

When we create an object whose type is defined in a C# library, does it live in Python runtime or CLR? Or 2 copies? How does garbage collection work in Python.NET ?

`import clr
clr.AddReference('assembly name here')
from DataViewerLibrary import PlotData 

p = PlotData()
p.Start()`

I want to use Python.NET at scale, and hope Python.NET's GC pause wouldn't be worse than pure .NET? Understanding bit of its architecture/design would help evaluate it.

Thanks!

Comment: pythonnet uses the standard Python C-API for both embedding and extending. So both garbage collectors for CLR and CPython work separately from each other. Unless you do the type conversion, the Python/CLR types live each in its own runtime without duplication.

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/